# Segfault on destructor

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, segmentation-fault

I'm being frustrated by a seg fault as I close my application and the destructor runs for this class.

vlocationdropdowns.h:

```
#include <QWidget>

class VLocationDropDowns : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  VLocationDropDowns(QString activeText, QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~VLocationDropDowns();
};
```

vlocationdropdowns.cpp:

```
VLocationDropDowns::VLocationDropDowns(QString activeText, QWidget *parent) :
 QWidget()//I've also had this as QWidget(parent, Qt::Widget)
{
}

VLocationDropDowns::~VLocationDropDowns()
{
}
```

I have created an object of this class (locationLineEdit is a pointer) in the constructor of another class (maybe I should say that this class inherits from QWidget as well):

```
locationDropDowns = new VLocationDropDowns(randomString, this);
```

but when the destructor of that class runs `delete locationDropDowns;` I get a segfault.

I'm new to managing memory so I realise that this is probably a noob question but I'm over messing with it now. I've commented out all the contents of the stuff I could in 
vlocationdropdowns.cpp and it's still seg faulting so I have no idea now. What could be causing this?

Comment: What does the macro Q_OBJECT?

Comment: It's a Qt macro. I think it does all the signals and slots stuff - to be honest I'm not too sure, I know Qt needs it though. I didn't tag this problem as Qt because I don't think Qt has anything to do with it - I could be wrong.

Comment: You're using a `new VLocationLineEdit`, but you've shown us some code from `VLocationDropDowns`. Didn't you mean to show us `VLocationLineEdit`?

Comment: Ja, sorry, fixed that - just copied the wrong line of code...

Comment: why don't you run via debugger?

Comment: Debugger is how I got to the fact that this is what's crashing it... This is as close as I'm getting with the debugger.

Comment: What's the type of `locationDropDowns`? Where have you declared it?

Comment: In the header of the class in which I call `locationDropDowns = new VLocationDropDowns(randomString, this);` I have `VLocationDropDowns *locationDropDowns;`

Comment: QObjects (which QWidget inherits from) will delete all its child objects when destructed, so when creating a child widget you should not delete it yourself: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject

Comment: @Emil that's intruiging but I think I should be allowed to delete this object... It may be deleted when its parent is, but I need to be able to delete it to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @j3frea: But you can not delete an object that has already been deleted by the framework.  On the other hand, that should only happen with the `QWidget(parent, ...)` constructor variant.

Comment: @Emil yeah - it's still confusing me a bit because the other class gets deleted just fine and it seems like it should have the same problem. I'm still not entirely sure what the problem is but I have got a clean destruction now. I'm still trying to figure it out properly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions I would try in this order:

- Code doesn't look wrong. Try a clean build.
- Put a printf in the destructor to see is it being called.
- Isolate down to a small program that just does the new and delete.
- Try it without the `Q_OBJECT`
- In the same way try creating and deleting a `QWidget` on its own instead.
- Why are you not using the parameters passed into the constructor?

Comment: I tried a clean build - nothing. I used debugger to see the destructor was being called, it is. The reason I posted this code is that I've commented out as much as I can of this class (to this extent) and it's still seg faulting. I have another class (VLocationLineEdit) which deconstructs fine. I thought maybe it was segfaulting because of a copy construct problem (hence no use of parameters in posted code). I'll build a new independent project and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe it is being destructed twice? Put the printf into the destructor and do *not* call the `delete` explicitly. Maybe some other code is calling the destructor first. (In QT, if a widget is registered with some window or somesuch, is it responsible for deleting it?)

Comment: @j3frea, did you try to the printfs/cout? What happened? Put `cout << "destructing" << endl;` into the destructor, and put `cout << "deleted" << endl;` immediately after the delete. Then tell us what happens.

Comment: Indeed, it could already have been deleted. Based on the comments above you could be onto something.

Comment: "destructing"
"The program has unexpectedly finished."

Comment: @aaron it seems maybe something else has destructed it first. Thanks, I'll look into this...

Comment: Yeah - thanks Aaron... the destructor was being called by something else... I cannot adequately express my gratitude with the words thank you but since English doesn't offer much else: thank you!

Comment: No problem! You mean that you saw the text "destructing" *twice* before the program crashed?

Comment: Jeezmarie, what do you have to do to get a helpful vote these days?  +1 for sticking it out.

Comment: @Aaron no, I put cout in the destructor of `VLocationDropDowns` and then right before I tried to delete it and saw that the destructor was being run earlier...